# navbar disappears when i switch to mobile view

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, responsive-design

When I minimize the browser to mobile, the burger icon should come up in mobile view and my navbar doesn't come up, but I am facing this issue. I am applying the codes I got from Github to my website. When I minimize it in the browser it switches to mobile view and the nav bar is gone, it disappears in the menus in my navbar. codes i use  [github](https://github.com/DevLHB/navbar-app)

```
navbar.js:
function Navbar() {
  const [isOpen,setIsOpen] =useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="per">
      <div className="logo">
      <div className="search">
      </div>
      <div className={`Items ${isOpen && "open "}`}>
   
        <a href="/home" to="/home">
          Home
        </a>
        <a href="/contact" to="/contact">
          contact
        </a>
        <a href="/about-us" to="/about-us">
          About Us
        </a>
        <div className={`nav-toggle ${isOpen && "open"}`}
                onClick={() => setIsOpen(!isOpen)}>
                
                    <div className="bar"></div>
                </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

navbar.css:
@media (max-width: 700px){
  .Items > a{
      margin: 15px;    
  }
  .Items{
      position: absolute;
      top: 60px;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      background: #7e77e1;
      left: 200px;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      transform: translateX(100%);
      transition: all .45s;
  }
   .Items > a::before{
      background: transparent;
  }
   .Items.open{
      transform: translateX(0);
  }

  .per > .nav-toggle{
      display: flex;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      cursor: pointer;
  }
  .nav-toggle > .bar{
      position: relative;
      width: 32px;
      height: 2px;
      background: #ffffff;
      transition: all 0.45s ease-in-out;
  }
  .nav-toggle >.bar::before,
  .nav-toggle >.bar::after{
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      height: 2px;
      background: #ffffff;
      border-radius: 2px;
      transition: all 0.45s ease-in-out;
  }
  .nav-toggle >.bar::before{
      width: 25px;
      transform: translateY(-8px);
      right: 0;
  }
  .nav-toggle >.bar::after{
      width: 32px;
      transform: translateY(8px);
  }
  .nav-toggle.open > .bar{
      transform: translateX(-40px);
      background: transparent;
  }
  .nav-toggle.open > .bar::before{
      width: 32px;
      transform: rotate(45deg) translate(26px, -26px);
  }
  .nav-toggle.open > .bar::after{
      transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(26px, 26px);
  }
}
```

Comment: not sure whats the issue , looked at the code in codesandbox and found it to be perfectly working , the navbar appears in responsive mode , with burger icon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My site Items section is on the left, I made 200px, it should be 0

```
Items{
  left:0px;
}
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be an answer or do you want to provide more information? If it's the latter then please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75399370/edit) your question.